# Tkinter : Text highlight appears while pressed but disappear next

Tags: python, tkinter, text, tags, highlight

I've been working on a Tkinter (Python) project that displays a list of strings using the Text widget recently, but I ran into an issue I couldn't manage to solve :
On startup, I want the first line to be highlighted, and when I click on up/down arrows, the highlight goes up/down, as a selection bar.
I succeed to do that, but the problem is that the highlight only appears when arrows are pressed, and when they are released, it disappear. I'd like it to stay even when I'm not pressing any key.

Here is my code :

```py
class Ui:
  def __init__(self):
    # the list I want to display in Text
    self.repos = repos

    # here is the entry keys are bind to
    self.entry = Entry(root)
    self.entry.pack()
    self.bind('<Up>', lambda i: self.changeIndex(-1))
    self.bind('<Down>', lambda i: self.changeIndex(1))

    # here is the Text widget
    self.lists = Text(root, state=NORMAL)
    self.lists.pack()
    
    # inits Text value
    for i in self.repos:
      self.lists.insert('insert', i + '\n')
    self.lists['state'] = DISABLED

    # variable I use to navigate with highlight
    self.index = 0
    self.lists.tag_add('curr', str(self.index) + '.0', str(self.index + 1) + '.0') # added + '.0' to make it look '0.0' instead of '0'
    self.lists.tag_config('curr', background='#70fffa', background='#000000')

    self.root.mainloop()

  def changeIndex(self, n):
    # error gestion (if < 0 or > len(repos), return)
    self.lists.tag_delete('curr')
    self.lists.tag_add('curr', str(self.index) + '.0', str(self.index + 1) + '.0')
    self.index = self.index + n
    # to make it scroll if cannot see :
    self.lists.see(str(self.index) + '.0')
```

I haven't seen any similar problem on Stack, so I asked, but do not hesitate to tell me if it is a duplicate.

Do you guys could help me please ? Thanks !

EDIT: Here is the full code if you want to give it a try : https://github.com/EvanKoe/stack_tkinter.git

*EDIT* : I added the main.py file (the """backend""" file that calls ui.py) to the demo repository. This way, you'll be able to run the project (be careful, there are "YOUR TOKEN" and "YOUR ORGANIZATION" strings in main.py you'll have to modify with your own token/organization. I couldn't push mine or Github would've asked me to delete my token)

Comment: Your code failed to run because `Ui` is not a widget and you called `self.bind(...)` inside `__init__()`.  Also `self.root` is undefined.

Comment: Ofc I defined self.root, Ui and all those things you said, I just didn't type them here to simplify the post. Also, the code runs and works well (it's just UI/UX improvements)

Comment: How can we help without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I just posted a github link with the full file :)

Comment: You should not use `tag_delete()` because it deletes all stuff related to the tag including the configured colors.  Use `tag_remove()` instead.

Comment: I tried it too but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: Did you notice that you called `tag_add(...)` before updating `self.index`?

Comment: The code linked, does not even work.

Comment: What do you get ? It works for me :/

Comment: we don't need your repo, we need a [mre]

Comment: That IS a minimal reproducible example. My use case is too specific, I removed what I could, it is minimal and allows you to see what the problem is

Comment: The class takes in an argument but none is given, so it gives error.

Comment: I send a list to the class, so there must not be problems ... I don't have any on my machine. Did you try the repo I just edited ?

Comment: Such type of code is not reproducible, you are asking us to put in alot of effort just to get to your code. Make a smaller example that will replicate this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem, and it was due to my event bindings. I made the decision (to improve the UX) to bind up/down arrows on the top Entry instead of binding em on the Text widget. I bind 4 events :

- Up arrow => move highlight up,
- Down arrow => move highlight down,
- Return key => calls get_name(), a function that returns the selected option,
- Any other Key => calls repo_filter(), a function that updates the displayed options in the Text widget, according to what has been typed in the Entry.

The problem was that pressing the up/down arrow was triggering "up/down key" event AND "any other key" event, so the highlight was removed since the Text value was refreshed.

To solve this problem, I just had to verify that the pressed key was neither up nor down arrow in the "any other key" event callback :

```py
def repo_filter(evt):
  if evt.keysym == 'Up' or evt.keysym == 'Down': # verify that pressed key
    return                                       # isn't '<Down>' or '<Up>'
  # filter Text widget
```

Also, I am sorry I didn't give you all the code at the beginning, because, indeed you couldn't guess about those event bindings.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me !

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you expect. Explanation below code

```
from tkinter import *

repos = ["one","two","three","four"]

class Ui:
  def __init__(self, parent):
    # the list I want to display in Text
    self.repos = repos

    # here is the entry keys are bind to
    self.entry = Entry(parent)
    self.entry.pack()
    self.entry.bind('<Up>', lambda i: self.changeIndex(-1))
    self.entry.bind('<Down>', lambda i: self.changeIndex(1))

    # here is the Text widget
    self.lists = Text(parent, state=NORMAL)
    self.lists.pack()

    
    
    # inits Text value
    for i in self.repos:
      self.lists.insert('insert', i + '\n')
    self.lists['state'] = DISABLED

    # variable I use to navigate with highlight
    self.index = 1
    self.lists.tag_add('curr', str(self.index) + '.0', str(self.index + 1) + '.0') # added + '.0' to make it look '0.0' instead of '0'
    self.lists.tag_config('curr', background='#70fffa', foreground='#000000')



  def changeIndex(self, n):
    print(f"Moving {n} to {self.index}")
    self.index = self.index + n
    self.index = min(max(self.index,0),len(self.repos))
    self.lists.tag_delete('curr')
    self.lists.tag_config('curr', background='#70fffa', foreground='#000000')
    self.lists.tag_add('curr', str(self.index) + '.0', str(self.index + 1) + '.0')
    # to make it scroll if cannot see :
    self.lists.see(str(self.index) + '.0')

root = Tk()
ui = Ui(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Few changes made to your code

- Changed the `Ui` function to accept the parent tk object as a parameter
- Changed `self.index` to be initialised to 1 rather than 0 since the first line on a text box is 1 not 0
- Bound the Up/Down keys to the entry box. Not sure why this is what you are going for but this seems to be what your comments indicate
- Added some checking code to limit the index value between 1 and len(repos)
- Re-created the tag style each time it is set since you delete the tag (this is why it wasn't showing)

I'd suggest that you look to bind the up/down button press to the text box rather than the entry box. Seems a bit strange to have to select a blank entry box to scroll up and down in a list.

Also, why aren't you just using the build in Tkinter list widget?

Comment: Hey ! Thanks a lot for your answer ! It didn't work for me, sadly... I bind up/down arrows to the entry, because I give this entry the focus on startup, and setting the focus on the Text widget before being able to use arrows would be really annoying. I use this class (Ui) from another python program, that's why I do everything in the __init__ function (I call it with (
from ui import Ui,    
variable = Ui(repos).get_name()), 
get_name() is a function that returns the highlighted Text)

Comment: This is why you are generally supposed to provide a minimal, executable example. By missing out parts of your code that were important, I've created an answer that doesn't work for you very specific use case (which isn't a good way to do it). I believe that this fixes you highlighting issue, you may just have to modify the code slightly to integrate it in to the rest of your code.

Comment: btw wouldn't it be better to inherit directly from `Tk`? or at least `Frame`? as that would allow to use `self` as parent and provide with the inherited methods

Comment: @Matiiss I would agree with you. There are better methods for creating this. I tried to fix the highlighting issue but had to fix other things to make this work as a standalone.

Comment: I already said it, but I have an entry on top that gets focus on startup, and I want to be able to use arrows while I am typing in it. Binding arrows to the Text widget would mean that the user must stop typing, then click with his mouse on the Text for it to take the focus, and then use arrows to select the one he wants. That's a really bad UX implementation from my point of view, that's why I bind it to entry.